# How to pass and update data into different tables in a single post function in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django

I have two models named `TokenDetails` and `TimeInterval`. I have to post a time into `TokenDetails` models into field `bookingdate` and in `TimeInterval` i have a field 'status' which by default is `True` and if the `bookingdate` field in `TokenDetails` is today's date I have to change the status of `TimeInterval` into `False`.

`customer/models.py`:

```
class TokenDetail(models.Model):
    customername=models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    bookingdate=models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    bookingtime=models.ForeignKey('vendor.TimeInterval',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    servicename=models.ForeignKey('vendor.ServiceDetail',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    vendorname=models.ForeignKey('vendor.VendorDetail',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
```

`vendor/models.py`:

```
class TimeInterval(models.Model):
    timeinterval=models.TimeField(default=None)
    serviceid=models.ForeignKey('ServiceDetail',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    userid=models.ForeignKey('accounts.User',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    status=models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.timeinterval)
```

`views.py`:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def tokendetailsAdd(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        customername=request.data.get('customerid')
        custname=User.objects.get(id=customername)

        bkngdate=request.data.get('bookingdate')

        bookingtime=request.data.get('bookingtime')
        bkngtime=TimeInterval.objects.get(id=bookingtime)

        servicename=request.data.get('servicename')
        srvcname=ServiceDetail.objects.get(id=servicename)

        vendorname=request.data.get('vendorname')
        vndrname=VendorDetail.objects.get(id=vendorname)
        
        if TokenDetail.objects.filter(bookingdate=datetime.date.today):
            timeinterval=TimeInterval.objects.get(id=bkngtime)
            timeinterval.save(update_fields=['status'])
            TimeInterval.objects.update(status=True)

       
        TokenDetail.objects.create(
             customername=custname,
             bookingdate=bkngdate,
             bookingtime=bkngtime,
             servicename=srvcname,
             vendorname=vndrname,

        )

        
    return Response('token registered')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't use blockquotes (`>`) for emphasis. They are for quotes, only.

Comment: Why do you have multiple models files? It is very unusual to have one class per file in Python. This isn't Java.

Comment: @Chris i have 3 apps in the project these 2 models are from different apps customer and vendor

Comment: Oh, so the files are really named like `TokenDetails/models.py`, not `TokenDetails.models.py`?

Comment: @Chris yeah its named as `customer/models.py` and `vendor/models.py` and these two models have two tables named `TokenDetails` and `TimeInterval` respectively

Comment: The terminology you are using is confusing. `TokenDetails` is a _model_, not a table. (Models often correspond to tables.)

Comment: @Chris ok am new to Django working on improving it. How can i update `TimeInterval ` status field when i have to add data to `TokenDetails` and meet the today's date condition?